# MySQL get rank of duplicate values based on their create dates

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way on how can I get the rank of the duplicate entries of my table based on their create dates. The older the date will be the one who will get the rank 1 and so on for the next duplicates. It should look like this:

```
id   number   create_date   rank
1      1         02/03        1
2      1         02/04        2
3      3         02/03        1
4      4         02/03        1
5      4         02/04        2
6      4         02/05        3
```

I tried searching for this but I can't understand well on how they implement it or more like it is not the way I wanted it to be. Hope someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
t.*,
@rank := if(@prevDate = create_date, @rank, @rank + 1) as rank,
@prevDate := create_date
from
your_table t 
, (select @rank := 0, @prevDate := null) var_init
order by create_date, id
```

Explanation:

Here

```
, (select @rank := 0, @prevDate := null) var_init
```

the variables are initalized. It's the same as writing

```
set @rank = 0;
set @prevDate = null;
select ... /*without the crossjoin*/;
```

Then the order of the columns in the select clause is important. First we check with this line

```
@rank := if(@prevDate = create_date, @rank, @rank + 1) as rank,
```

if the current row has the same date as the previous row. The @prevDate holds the value of the previous row. If yes, the `@rank` variable stays the same, if not it's incremented.

In the next line

```
@prevDate := create_date
```

we set the `@prevDate` variable to the value of the current row. That's why the order of the columns in the `select` clause is important.

Finally, since we're checking with the previous row, if the dates differ, the `order by` clause is important.